# XStream Alias Compatibility With Previous Files Content Structure

Tags: java, exception, alias, xstream

I am facing the following issue:
I've got a file automatically created with XSTream that is properly write and read.

My question is that I want to move a class (InstallationUser) from one package to another one but this is creating a parsing exception on XStream:

> com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException:
>   myproject.data.clientconfiguration.InstallationUser :
>   myproject.data.clientconfiguration.InstallationUser
>   ---- Debugging information ---- message             : myproject.data.clientconfiguration.InstallationUser cause-exception
>   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
>   cause-message       :
>   myproject.data.clientconfiguration.InstallationUser class
>   : java.util.TreeMap required-type       : java.util.TreeMap
>   converter-type      :
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter path 
>   :
>   /CLIENT_CONFIGURATION/network/NETWORK/users/entry/myproject.data.clientconfiguration.InstallationUser
>   class[1]            :
>   myproject.data.clientconfiguration.InstallationDetails
>   converter-type[1]   :
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
>   class[2]            : java.util.Vector converter-type[2]   :
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter
>   class[3]            :
>   myproject.data.clientconfiguration.ClientConfiguration version
>   : null

After that, the data that I am loading is lost.

I am guessing that this is my fault because I don't make an Alias of this class before.

I checked and If I don't make the moving of the class from one package to the other, it works without problem.

So, what I want to know if there is some way to advise XStream parser that the previous class:

> myproject.data.clientconfiguration.InstallationUser

Could be now on:

> myproject.data.clientconfiguration.newpackage.InstallationUser

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set alias to match your old class name, and you can move your class to any package you want.

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.alias("myproject.data.clientconfiguration.InstallationUser", InstallationUser.class);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not understood properly how alias worked and this example that you gave me, is perfect to make me understand and solve the issue.